# gpg2 migration from ubuntu to fedora leads to missing secret key

Tags: linux, encryption, thunderbird, gnupg, enigmail

I'm using gnupg with thunderbird via enigmail. Everything is up and running fine on my notebook with ubuntu (kubuntu). Now I tried transfering my keys and settings to my new system running fedora. Although everything seems to be in order, I cant decrypt my mails on the new system. Enigmail extension states "Kein passender geheimer Schlüssel zur Entschlüsselung gefunden" - No matching private key. I will list my steps in more detail below:
My first approach was to delete my gnupg folder on the new system via `rm -R .gnupg/` and copy the folder from my notebook via `scp -rp`. That way not only all keys should have been transfered but also the corresponding trust.

```
[username@localhost ~]$ gpg2 --list-keys
/home/username/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
-------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2016-11-20 [SCA] [verfällt: 2018-11-20]
      0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEFXXXXXXXX
uid        [ ultimativ ] Some Name <AAA@some-domain.com>
sub   rsa4096 2016-11-20 [E] [verfällt: 2018-11-20]

[username@localhost ~]$ gpg2 --list-secret-keys
/home/username/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
-------------------------------------------
sec   rsa4096 2016-11-20 [SCA] [verfällt: 2018-11-20]
      0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEFXXXXXXXX
uid        [ ultimativ ] Some Name <AAA@some-domain.com>
ssb   rsa4096 2016-11-20 [E] [verfällt: 2018-11-20]
```

Although everything looked fine i could not decrypt my mails. (FYI: I did copy my thunderbird profile aswell - IMAP). After some research I've read that there might be a version missmatch. 
Notebook[ubuntu] version (both gpg and gpg2) :

```
gpg2 --version / gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.15
```

New sytem[fedora] version:

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.22
...
Home: ~/.gnupg
------
gpg2 --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.1
...
Home: /home/username/.gnupg
```

So I tried the export/import function. With:

```
gpg2 -ao some-name-public.key --export 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEFXXXXXXXX
```

and

```
gpg2 -ao some-name-private.key --export-secret-keys 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEFXXXXXXXX
```

I stored my pub and sec keys, copied them again via scp to the new system, where I imported them. For the private key the result was:

```
[username@localhost ~]$ gpg2 --import some-name-private.key
gpg: Schlüssel XXXXXXXX: geheimer Schlüssel importiert
gpg: Schlüssel XXXXXXXX: "Some Name <AAA@some-domain.com>" nicht geändert
gpg: Anzahl insgesamt bearbeiteter Schlüssel: 1
gpg:                             unverändert: 1
gpg:              gelesene geheime Schlüssel: 1
gpg:            geheime Schlüssel importiert: 1
```

Afterwards I modified the trust level to ultimative via

```
gpg2 --edit-key 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEFXXXXXXXX
```

Edit function states "Geheimer Schlüssel ist vorhanden." - Secret key available. But Enigmail is still not able to decrypt my messages. Enigmail uses gpg2 binaries, but I repeated the import procedure for gpg anyway with no change at all. Since everything is working fine on my notebook, I am certain that that nothing is wrong with the actual test mail. I can't figure out what's wrong here. I hope that someone can help me on this issue.

Comment: Are you able to decrypt the mails on your old computer? `scp`ing the GnuPG home directory should be totally fine, if your numeric user ID (not the user name) is different also run `chown -R ~/.gnupg`. Also consider running `killall gpg-agent` before copying the keys -- maybe GnuPG picked up and keeps some old information. Signing off and on again or rebooting would have the same effect.

Comment: @JensErat I'm able to decrypt the message on my old computer (my notebook). User name and ID are identical but I tried the owner modification since it won't hurt in my case. I now repeated the copy process via `scp` after killing the gpg-agent and even tried relogging with no effect.